# Rally sample App error

Tags: javascript, rally, appsdk2

I'm trying to create a new app for Rally, and I'm new to both the Rally SDK and JavaScript. I found a tutorial on building your first Rally app, and I tried starting there. However, I'm getting an error when following the example.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'refresh' of undefined
```

At first I assumed I was doing something wrong, but eventually I copied & pasted the entire sample application in, only to discover it's happening for the sample project too.

Anything to point me in the right direction of successfully debugging this would be appreciated!

The entire `App.js` that I'm using (from the example) is this:

```
Ext.define('CustomApp', {
  extend: 'Rally.app.App',
  componentCls: 'app',
  items: { html: '<a href="https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc2/doc/">App SDK 2.0rc2 Docs</a>' },
  launch: function () {
    this.iterationCombobox = this.add({
      xtype: 'rallyiterationcombobox',
      listeners: {
        change: this._onIterationComboboxChanged,
        ready: this._onIterationComboboxLoad,
        scope: this
      }
    });
  },

  _onIterationComboboxLoad: function () {
    var addNewConfig = {
      xtype: 'rallyaddnew',
      recordTypes: ['User Story', 'Defect'],
      ignoredRequiredFields: ['Name', 'ScheduleState', 'Project'],
      showAddWithDetails: false,
      listeners: {
        beforecreate: this._onBeforeCreate,
        scope: this
      }
    };

    this.addNew = this.add(addNewConfig);

    var cardBoardConfig = {
      xtype: 'rallycardboard',
      types: ['Defect', 'User Story'],
      attribute: 'ScheduleState',
      storeConfig: {
        filters: [this.iterationCombobox.getQueryFromSelected()]
      }
    };
    this.cardBoard = this.add(cardBoardConfig);
  },

  _onBeforeCreate: function (addNewComponent, record) {
    record.set('Iteration', this.iterationCombobox.getValue());
  },

  _onIterationComboboxChanged: function () {
    var config = {
      storeConfig: {
        filters: [this.iterationCombobox.getQueryFromSelected()]
      }
    };

    this.cardBoard.refresh(config);
  }
});
```

Comment: Where did the sample app come from?  Is it on the developer portal or included with Rally App Builder?  We should fix the sample.

Comment: @KyleMorse, that sample came from the developer portal. https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc2/doc/#!/guide/first_app

Comment: Thanks- I'll make sure that gets cleaned up.  It's a bummer when the tutorial is broken!

Comment: Thanks! I will say I think the documentation for your SDK is really thorough though (discovered the live preview feature for controls today!). Also, the fact that you provide the app builder is great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code instead. The source is available in [this git hub repo](https://github.com/nmusaelian-rally/story-board).

```
Ext.define('CustomApp', {
    extend: 'Rally.app.TimeboxScopedApp',
    componentCls: 'app',
    scopeType: 'iteration',
    onScopeChange: function(scope) {
        this._iteration = scope.record.get('_ref');
        if (!this.down('#addNew')) {
         var addNewConfig = {
            xtype: 'rallyaddnew',
            itemId: 'addNew',
            recordTypes: ['User Story', 'Defect'],
            ignoredRequiredFields: ['Name', 'ScheduleState', 'Project'],
            showAddWithDetails: false,
            listeners: {
                beforecreate: this._onBeforeCreate,
                scope: this
            }
        }; 
    }


        this.addNew = this.add(addNewConfig);
        if(!this.board) {
             this.board = this.add({
                xtype: 'rallycardboard',
                storeConfig: {
                    filters: [scope.getQueryFilter()]
                }
            });
        } else {
            this.board.refresh({
                storeConfig: {
                    filters: [scope.getQueryFilter()]
                }
            });
        }
        this.iteration = scope.getRecord();
    },

    _onBeforeCreate: function(addNewComponent, record) {
    record.set('Iteration', this._iteration);
}
});
```